# Google Identity Services Login with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-identity, google-one-tap

I'm trying to implement Google Identity Services Login without third parties, everything works well because I get the response when I try to sign in, except for the error shown in the console:

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()"
```

This is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    try {
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id:
          "CODE.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        callback: handleCallbackResponse,
      });

      google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById("buttonDiv"), {
        theme: "outline",
        size: "large",
        text: "continue_with",
      });

      window.google.accounts.id.prompt();
    } catch (e) {
      alert("Error", e);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);


function handleCallbackResponse(response) {
    //code
  }

return (<div id="buttonDiv"></div>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only handles [authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/overview) (who is the user) and you should handle [authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview) (what is the user) as well in order to grant user access to server resources.

Response error with status code 401 tells that you are **unauthorized**. That means you have to get an access token and use it in your HTTP requests' headers. For that, you can use [initTokenClient](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient) like in the following example:

```js
const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
  client_id: <YOUR_CLIENT_ID>,
  scope: <YOUR_SCOPES>, // these are defined in Google Cloud console within enabled APIs
  hint: 'user@gmail.com',
  callback: (tokenResponse) => {
    // store access token in cookie
  }
})

client.requestAccessToken({ prompt: '', hint: 'user@gmail.com' })
```

The best way to do this is to wrap it in a function and call it on user event (e.g., click). Otherwise, browsers' default settings usually block popups and redirects which may produce UX issues.